# ArrayList of Entites Random Movement

Tags: java, game-physics

I have an arraylist of entites that I want to move randomly. No matter what I do, they won't move. Here is my female class:

```
public class Female extends Entity {
static int femaleX = 0;
static int femaleY = 0;
double walkSpeed = .1f;
Random rand = new Random();
int random;
int dir;

Player player;

public Female(int posX, int posY) {
    super(posX, posY);

}

public void update() {
    posX += femaleX;
    posY += femaleY;

    moveFemale();

}

public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
    g2d.drawImage(getFemaleImg(), posX, posY, null);
    if (Player.showBounds == true) {
        g2d.draw(getBounds());
    }
}

public Image getFemaleImg() {
    ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("res/female.png");
    return ic.getImage();
}

public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(posX, posY, getFemaleImg().getHeight(null),
            getFemaleImg().getWidth(null));
}

public void moveFemale() {
    random = rand.nextInt(3);
    System.out.println(random);

    if (random == 0) {
        dir = 0;
        posX -= (int) walkSpeed;
    }
}
      }
```

And here is how I update the female class in the main class:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    player.update();

    for(int i = 0; i < females.size(); i++){
        Female tempFemale = females.get(i);
        tempFemale.update();
    }
    repaint();
}
```

If I do something like this(in the female update method):

```
public void update() {
    posX += femaleX;
    posY += femaleY;

    posX -= walkSpeed;

}
```

The characters move with no problem. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `femaleX` and `femaleY` are zero. Adding them to `posX` and `posY` doesn't change those variables, but adding a nonzero variable like walkSpeed does.

EDIT: For the randomness problem, I'll have to take a stab in the dark since I can't see all of your code, but *perhaps* you aren't calling your moveFemale method, which is the movement method with randomness in it. The update method is completely deterministic. If you want the females to move randomly, either call the moveFemale method or add randomness to the update method.

This is an example of a general rule in object-oriented programming: it's bad to have two methods (update and moveFemale) that appear to do the same or very similar things.

Comment: Edit the question to add the new problem if you like.

Comment: I still have the same problem where the random portion of my code refuses to work. The random code is in the moveFemale() method.

Comment: Oh sorry I tried adding the moveFemale(); into the update but it still doesn't work... I tried to set femaleX = 2 and then do femaleX -= walkspeed; , but the entities still just sit there.

Comment: Just to be clear, femaleX -= walkspeed won't modify position, as femaleX isn't the entity's x coordinate (posX is). Are you still modifying posX?

Comment: I just switched to posX -= walkspeed which is the characters coordinates and it still doesn't work. However, if I don't use random movement they will move. Random is working though because I have it printing out the rand variable. The entities just never move... thanks for helping, I really appreciate it!

Comment: I solved it, apparently I forgot but I cast walkSpeed as an int in my random code, so since it was .1f, it rounded down to 0. *Phew* Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

femaleX and femaleY are never non-zero, as far as I can see.